# PowerShell: How to find a word within a line of text and modify the data behind it

Tags: string, powershell, substring

I'm looking for a way to find a word with a value behind it in a piece of text and then update the value.
Example:

In the file the are multiple occurrences of 'schema="anon" maxFileSize="??????" maxBufferSize="123"'
I want to find all the lines containing maxFileSize and then update the unknown value ?????? to 123456.

So far, I came up with this:

```
cls
$Files = "C:\temp1\file.config","C:\temp2\file.config"
$newMaxFileSize = "123456"

ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    If ((Test-Path $File -PathType Leaf) -eq $False) {
        Write-Host "File $File doesn't exist"
    } Else {
        # Check content of file and select all lines where maxFileSize isn't equal to 123456 yet
        $Result = Get-Content $File | Select-String -Pattern "maxFileSize" -AllMatches | Select-String -Pattern "123456" -NotMatch -AllMatches
        Write-Host $Result
        <#
            ROUTINE TO UPDATE THE SIZE
        #>
    }
}
```

Yet, I have no clue how to find the word "maxFileSize", let alone how to update the value behind it...

Comment: please, add some sample lines of data - realistic ones - to your Question & wrap them in formatting markers so that they are presented correctly.

Comment: if it's a config file you'd be better off finding a way to parse the file (e.g. ```ConvertFrom-Json```, or ```[xml] (Get-Content)```, etc), edit the in-memory object model, and then save it back to the config file rather than try to manipulate the raw text. Things like line breaks, other whitespace and escape characters in the config file will easily trip up any attempts to match the raw file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input file is actually XML, use the following XPath expression to locate all nodes that have a `maxFileSize` attribute (regardless of value):

```
# Parse input file as XML
$configXml = [xml](Get-Content $file) 

# Use Select-Xml to find relevant nodes
$configXml |Select-Xml '//*[@maxFileSize]' |ForEach-Object {
  # Update maxFileSize attribute value
  $_.Node.SetAttribute('maxFileSize','123456')
}

# Overwrite original file with updated XML
$configXml.Save($file.FullName)
```

---

If the config file is some archaic format for which no readily available parser exists, use the `-replace` operator to update the value where appropriate:

```
$Results = @(Get-Content $File) -creplace '(?<=maxFileSize=")[^"]*(?=")','123456'
```

The pattern used above, `(?<=maxFileSize=")[^"]*(?=")`, describes:

```
(?<=             # Positive look-behind assertion, this pattern MUST precede the match
  maxFileSize="  # literal string `maxFileSize="`
)                # Close look-behind
  [^"]*          # Match 0 or more non-" characters
(?=              # Positive look-ahead assertion, this pattern MUST succeed the match
  "              # literal string `"`
)                # Close look-ahead
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation! I shall give it a try :)